# How to add audio to Recycler View items

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer, onclicklistener

I'm making an app which will show different types of guitar and when the user will tap on the image(or text) of a particular type of guitar, it will play a riff of that type(eg. tapping on electric guitar will play an electric guitar riff). Here's my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guitar_basics);

    recGuitarTypes();

}

private void recGuitarTypes(){

    recGtypes = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.viewGuitarTypes);

    GuitarTypesRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new GuitarTypesRecyclerViewAdapter(this);

    recGtypes.setAdapter(adapter);
    recGtypes.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

    ArrayList<Guitar> arrGuitar = new ArrayList<>();

    arrGuitar.add(new Guitar("Nylon String Spanish", "https://inside-guitar.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Savarez-Flamenco-Guitar-Strings.jpg"));
    arrGuitar.add(new Guitar("Steel String Acoustic","https://hearthemusicplay.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/steelstringguitar-e1494992902529-1140x638.jpg"));
    arrGuitar.add(new Guitar("Electric Guitar","https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/papiVxAvWm3QaDAD8fSdqS-970-80.jpg.webp"));

    adapter.setGuitars(arrGuitar);
    
        
}
```

I wanted to check if the code worked which is why I tried to test it using a single audio file in my "raw" folder applied to all the items in the RecyclerView. It didn't. Here's the code if you wanna check that out:

```
recGtypes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(view.getContext(), R.raw.steel_string);

            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I have added the answer , if it works and something you were looking for , mark it as an correct answer else comment below the answer !

Answer (score 0):

can you try below code ?

```html
recGtypes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

          AssetFileDescriptor file = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.steel_string);
          mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getFileDescriptor(), file.getStartOffset(),  file.getLength());
          
          file.close();
          mediaPlayer.prepare();
          mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```